# Apache HTTP Request ends in exception on RESTful webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I need to test a RESTful webservice* (with spring) with JUnit. I tested the Webservice using IntelliJs build in Testing Tool and it works well. So now I'm using ApacheHttpClient to perform a POST request on that webservice. Im starting the RESTful webservice and then execute this code

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
             .setScheme("http")
             .setHost("localhost")
             .setPort(8080)
             .setPath("/register")
             .build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "test"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "test"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
response.close();
```

But this ends in an exception on the webservice saying:

> A servlet request to the URI http://localhost:8080/register contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected. UT005023: Exception handling request to /error

Full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/96aJtaS5

*Full source code is available at: https://github.com/pkalauner-tgm/dezsys09-java-webservices
Thx for your help

Comment: Could it be due to calling close() on the response before reading it's body?

Comment: The response is actually unimportant for me so I closed it until the request has been executed. And as I said the exception appears on the webservice and not on this code. PS: The request at this URL is supposed to create a User and saving it so the response would be OK or not ok or sth. like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the content type of the request to json by

```
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
```